# Yocto - File is not present in my image (but present in tmp/work directory in build environment)

Tags: yocto

I add a recipe that create a file helloworld under directory /myDir.
After building image, I could see the file under /build/tmp/work/../../mydir/helloworld.
But the same is not present on the board.

```
app = "helloworld"
usrdir = "/myDir"
FILES_${PN} += "${usrdir}/${app}"
FILES_${PN}-dbg += "${usrdir}/.debug"

do_install() {
    install -D -m 0755 ${B}/${app} ${D}/myDir/${app}
}
```

If I install helloworld under /usr/bin, then the file is present on the board.

What is wrong? Why the file installed in /usr/bin are deployed while files in /myDir are not? Any idea?

Regards,
Suresh.

Comment: please post your whole recipe

Comment: Add `mkdir -p ${D}/myDir` before `install -D -m 0755 ${B}/${app} ${D}/myDir/${app}`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. This turned out to be problem with the way we are copying .